# SharePoint2010 configured with Win, FBA and SSRS with Integrated,reports working fine but after enable the anonymous subsite reports are not working

Tags: forms-authentication, reporting-services, anonymous-authentication, windows-authentication

Site Details

- SharePoint web application
- Enable Windows Authentication with NTLM
- Enable FBA(With appropriate setting)
- Reporting Services with Integrated Mode
- Reports configured with Trusted Account

And all reports were working fine!!

- On same web application I have enabled Anonymous Access to create anonymous sub site. 
  After changing this setting my reports are not workig. Please let us know what changes we need to do to work all together.

Answer (score 0):

Sushant,

Extract from MSDN Page:

> SharePoint personalization is also not supported on the Reporting
>   Services pages. Report Server integration is not supported if the
>   SharePoint Web application is enabled for Anonymous access.
>   Ref: [Unsupported SharePoint Features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213532.aspx#bkmk_unsupportedsharepoint)

Read more about this here: 
[Installation Considerations for Reporting Services in SharePoint Integrated Mode](http://whitepages.unlimitedviz.com/2010/05/installation-considerations-for-reporting-services-in-sharepoint-integrated-mode/)